# UIScrollView with UIButtons - Scroll View won't scroll when touch began on button

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios8

I just updated to xCode 6 and iOS 8 and I noticed something very weird with my app. In my app I have a scrollview with several buttons within it, aligned horizontally. I set it up to create my own custom scrollable tab bar controller. Before the update to iOS 8 and xCode 6 everything was working perfect, but now I realized that when I try to scroll the scrollview left or right, and my initial touch was within one of the buttons in the scroll view, then no scrolling happens. However if I touch in-between the buttons then scrolling works as expected. I think it's some issue where the button is registering the touch and it is as if the scrollview never got touched. But this was 100% working before perfectly so i do not what is going on!!

Comment: Just for anyone googling here. I had a weird one where, updating to XCode6, for some reason it TURNED OFF (!) "User Interaction Enabled" on a view, in Storyboard. Who knows why!  I turned it on and all was well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a subclass of UIScrollView and set it's cancelContentTouches value to TRUE and my problem was solved

Comment: Doesn't work for me well. Its not smooth like in 7.1

Comment: I think you mean this method -(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view

Comment: There is no `cancelContentTouches`. Do you mean `canCancelContentTouches`? I set it to `YES` and it still didn't work for me.

Comment: As rozochkin said, overriding `(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view` and returning `YES` fixes the problem. Seems strange that you have to subclass `UIScrollView` to get this basic behaviour to work.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing UIScrollView and adding code below into .m file, did solve my scrolling  freeze problem under iOS 8.

Code:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
    }
}
```

This solution was found in pasta12's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25900859/3433059

Comment: Adding this solution to the other given solutions was required in my case.

Answer (score 0):

No need to subclass ScrollView
Just use this :

```
yourScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan =yourScrollView.delaysContentTouches;
```