# ios 8 - buttons in horizontal scroll view intercepting pan event - scroll does not work

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios8

I have a horizontal scroll view with a line of buttons. The scroll view will not scroll unless I do an extremely fast swipe.

If I set the buttons to userInteractionEnabled = NO, then the scrolling works as expected, but of course, then the buttons don't work at all.

This app worked fine in iOS 7 and before.  It seems to be a iOS 8 "feature".  I did notice that I can catch the button's drag event, but I don't know how to redirect it back to the scrollView.

I'm thinking I'll need to replace my buttons with UIViews and manage the events myself but I'd be grateful if someone has other ideas or solutions.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet but I just noticed I have the exact same issue. Will post a solution when I find one.

Comment: FWIW, I rewrote the buttons to be UILabels and just managed with a UITapGestureRecognizer.  There are some comments on the Apple forums with regards to this bug under the iOS8 beta category.

Comment: Oops, I did find a solution, but forgot to post. Will post a little `UIScrollView` subclass in case you want to simplify what you did.

Answer (score 39):

I found that in iOS 8, the UIScrollView's underlying UIPanGestureRecognizer is not respecting the UIScrollView's delaysContentTouches property.  I consider this an iOS 8 bug.  Here's my workaround:

```
theScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = theScrollView.delaysContentTouches
```

Comment: Fix works, but there is a problem: "highlighted" button image is not displayed when user puts finger in button.

Comment: I really appreciate for your answer.

Comment: Definitely the clearest solution I have seen yet… thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I've had this problem with a UITableView which has custom UITableViewCells with UIButtons on it. I put this in my UITableview class.

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return YES;
}
```

Solved my problem.

EDIT: Just to clearify, you can create a subclass of UIScrollview and add this to solve the problem.

Comment: This one seems to be the right solution. Tried the touchedShouldBegin: method and had issues consistently recognising the button tap (as mentioned by Leonardo)

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Saved me a huge headache, thank you! This worked for iOS 5.1 and up.

Answer (score 10):

This hack works for me:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *nothingTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
nothingTap.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:nothingTap];
```

credit: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/241467

Comment: This works if you don't have to support iOS 5.1. The solution from Daniel worked across the board for me.

Answer (score 9):

I made a subclass of `UIScrollView` to fix this issue. You only need this method in it:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
    }
}
```

Then just remember to set the class to your subclass in the storyboard if you're using one and you're good to go.

Comment: Fixed mine too -- with a UISegmentedControl embedded in the scroll view. Many thanks!

Comment: I tried that, and it fixed the UIScrollView, but sometimes my buttons aren't responding on the first touch, did anyone else noticed that same behavior?

Comment: @Leonardo yep, noticing the same thing - so the solution above doesnt really solve the problem. Might have to, annoyingly, change all the buttons to views.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I solved it by creating a subclass of `UIScrollView` and set it's `cancelContentTouches` value to `TRUE` and its working fine.

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
       return YES;
}
```

Hope it will work for you.