# iOS 8 - buttons not responding in horizontal scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8

I have a horizontal scrollView with a lot of buttons inside but none of them responding. The scrollview works well.

Here is how my scrollview is declared, pretty standard :

```
_slotsScrollView = [UIScrollView new];
_slotsScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_slotsScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
_slotsScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
_slotsScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
_slotsScrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

The scrollview contains one main view which contains all the buttons, the structure is this one :

```
--UIScrollView
----UIView
  ----UIButton
  ----UIButton
  ----UIButton ...
```

I've already try a lot of tricks (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800325/ios-8-buttons-in-horizontal-scroll-view-intercepting-pan-event-scroll-does-n) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649639/uibutton-does-not-work-when-it-in-uiscrollview)) but none of them have solved my problem, any idea ?

Comment: Is the container view big enough to contain all of the buttons? e.g. do all of the buttons fall within the bounds of the containerView?

Comment: Oh god, i'm so stupid, i've spend two hours because i just forgot to set the height of my container view. Thank you Paul, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the frames of all the buttons fall within the containerView's bounds.