# Subclassed UIScrollView detects touches within buttons but is otherwise unresponsive to user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a vertical UIScrollView that has several large buttons taking up most of the space in the scroll view. For this reason I've had to subclass the scroll view following this post [ios 8 - buttons in horizontal scroll view intercepting pan event - scroll does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800325/ios-8-buttons-in-horizontal-scroll-view-intercepting-pan-event-scroll-does-n/25900859#25900859)) and override the following class method:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    NSLog(@"calling this function 2");
    NSLog(@"count = %d", count);
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseMoved so returning no");
        return NO;
    }


    else
    {
        NSLog(@"returning super");
        NSLog(@"returning whatever this value is %d 0/1", [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view]);
        [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
        return [super touchesShouldBegin:touches withEvent:event inContentView:view];
    }
}
```

When I run my app, this above function is called when a button is tapped but the function is not called when I drag anywhere in the scroll view, inside or outside a button. And the scroll view doesn't scroll regardless of where I try to drag.

Here's all my code related to the scroll view (it's set up with IB):

```
            smallView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            smallView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(smallView.frame.size.width, smallView.frame.size.height*1.4);
            smallView.delegate = self;
```

And here's the buttons-related code in case that matters:

```
NSArray *buttonsArray = @[button1, button2, button3, button4, button5];
for (int i = 0; i < [buttonsArray count]; i++) {
    UIButton *button = buttonsArray[i];
    button.tag = i+1;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(p_motivationButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Why is my scroll view not scrolling and not even calling `touchesShouldBegin`?

Comment: y u return no when the touchphase is moved ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I don't know, that can change, but the function never enters that branch of the logic anyway.

Comment: where did u implement the touched moved method  ? the touches begin method cannot intercept touched moved event. It will only detect the start point of the touch event.

Comment: have aloot at the fifth paragraph https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:

Comment: It explains why scrolling event aren't sent to the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView()` as follows:

```
override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if let _ = view as? UIControl {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }
}
```